# jstree: prevent parent node from becoming leaf node

Tags: jstree, drag-and-drop

I have a simple two-level jstree which allows drag and drop of leaf nodes between parent nodes. When a parent node contains only one leaf, when I drag the leaf out, the parent node "becomes" a leaf node. I would like to prevent this but I can't find any documentation telling me how to do this.

I have included a pictorial representation of what is happening. Note that in picture 2, the parent node "Proctor" thinks it's a leaf node in terms of appearance. I can still drag items into it and it again becomes a non-leaf node. It makes a lot more sense for this interface if the parent nodes maintain the group icon appearance whether they are empty or not. Note also that when the tree is initially open, empty parent nodes appear with the group icon (which is a good thing).

Here's the tree as it appears initially:

[image]

and here's the tree after I drag Paul Postler from Proctor to Contributor:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out one way to do it, but it isn't particularly clean. Any other answers would be much appreciated. Here's what I added to my bound move_node.jstree code:

```
var oldParent = document.getElementById(
    (oldIsUnassigned) ? "Unassigned" : "P" + oldRoleId);
var className = oldParent.className.replace("jstree-leaf", "");
if (className.indexOf("jstree-drop") < 0) className += " jstree-drop";
if (className.indexOf("jstree-open") < 0) className += " jstree-open";
oldParent.className = className;
```